# Datatable cannot trigger childrow

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to replicate

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html

this code.

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Frontend JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 'tr'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0
    }],
    order: [1, 'asc']
  });
});
```

CSS

```
td.details-control {
  background: url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
  background: url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

I would like to use the information on the last column to display some values in the child row but it is not working even when I think I have almost copied and pasted the example code.

Why is this?

My fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/rfbeezhg/1/

Comment: you have written many extra code as well...

Comment: @RohitasBehera like what? only extra codes are css codes

Comment: $(obj).parents('td:first').siblings(':eq(2)').find(':text').val(text);

Comment: @RohitasBehera oh oops sorry wrong link

Comment: @RohitasBehera updated